# How to skip a column when writing to a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

Sorry if this has been asked, but is it possible to skip a column when writing to a csv file?

Here is the code I have:

```
with open("list.csv","r") as f:
    reader2 = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader2:
        url = 'http://peopleus.intelius.com/results.php?ReportType=33&qi=0&qk=10&qp='+row
        req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        html = response.read()
        retrieved_name = b'class="singleName">(.*?)<\/h1'
        retrieved_number = b'<div\sclass="phone">(.*?)<\/div'
        retrieved_nothing = b"(Sorry\swe\scouldn\\'t\sfind\sany\sresults)"
        if re.search(retrieved_nothing,html):
            noth = re.search(retrieved_nothing.decode('utf-8'),html.decode('utf-8')).group(1)
            add_list(phone_data, noth)
        else:
            if re.search(retrieved_name,html):
                name_found = re.search(retrieved_name.decode('utf-8'),html.decode('utf-8')).group(1)
            else:
                name_found = "No name found on peopleus.intelius.com"
            if re.search(retrieved_number,html):
                number_found = re.search(retrieved_number.decode('utf-8'),html.decode('utf-8')).group(1)
            else:
                number_found = "No number found on peopleus.intelius.com"
            add_list(phone_data, name_found, number_found)
        with open('column_skip.csv','a+', newline='') as mess:
            writ = csv.writer(mess, dialect='excel')
            writ.writerow(phone_data[-1])
        time.sleep(10)
```

Assuming that there is data in the first three rows of column_skip.csv, can I have my program start writing its info in column 4?

Comment: Array slicing is your friend. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/289/indexing-and-slicing#t=201701181809339640686&a=syntax

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, don't use csv.writer method and write it as an simple file write operation:

```
  `file_path ='your_csv_file.csv'
   with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
       #following are the data you want to write to csv
       fp.write("%s, %s, %s" % ('Name of col1', 'col2', 'col4'))
       fp.write("\n")`
```

I hope this helps...